# Is it possible to upload an initial solution and check if it is feasible

Tags: pyomo

I would like to know, that after building a pyomo model, if it is possible to send to the model an arbitrary solution and make it check if it is feasible. If yes return true and return false if the uploaded solution is infeasible

I expect to receive a true/false result depending on the feasibility of the uploaded solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no general utility for checking if a model is feasible at an arbitrary point but something very close to what you want can be found here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/contrib/gdpopt/util.py#L176

You could implement your own `is_feasible` function by copying the code that loops over the constraints and variables.

Comment: This is very interesting. I am not the original asker, but I tried to do something similar . I used the solution from the solver and used the `value()` function to evaluate the constraints as booleans. However, I found that the solver' numeric precision was different of the one in Python. I had to make a round function to avoid having things like `1.00000000 == 1.00000000000000002112`, which returns False in Python, but obviously, the constraint was ok. In your link, it has `config.constraint_tolerance` parameter. Is this something that can be used to avoid getting those precision errors?

Comment: The `constraint_tolerance` parameter is specific to the GDPopt metasolver that the example came from but you could add your own keyword option to a similar function for specifying the constraint tolerance. There is no global tolerance parameter in Pyomo.

Answer (score 0):

One verbose but effective solution is to fix all your variables to their current value. 
There are multiple ways to iterate over all model components of a certain type, you can iterate over variables and call `model.var_name.fix()`.

I haven't tested this but it should work.